# Operator < cannot be applied to operands of type "method group"

Tags: c#

I've tried to make whole game loop into a method.

I have two methods for counting.

```
 public void CountScoreForPlayerOne()
        {
            Score++;
        }
        public void CountScoreForPlayerTwo()
        {
            Score++;
        }
```

And when I try to compare the scores.

```
if (CountScoreForPlayerOne > CountScoreForPlayerTwo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There are no more cards the game is over!");
                Console.WriteLine($"{FirstPlayer} won the game");
            }
            else if (CountScoreForPlayerOne < CountScoreForPlayerTwo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There are no more cards the game is over!");
                Console.WriteLine($"{SecondPlayer} won the game");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There are no more cards the game is over!");
                Console.WriteLine("None won the game");
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"The final score is {FirstPlayer} {Score} - {SecondPlayer} {Score}");
```

It says that the Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'method group'. I don't have idea how to fix this.

Thanks,

Comment: As the error states, you're trying to compare methods not the values. Should call the methods first.. `if (CountScoreForPlayerOne() > CountScoreForPlayerTwo())`

Comment: I don't know if this is intended, but why you increment only one field if you want to count the score for two different players? Use two different fields like `ScorePlayer1` and `ScorePlayer2`.

Comment: Is this a typo? In order to compare a methods return-value you have to **call** the method, which is done by using parantheses: `CountScoreForPlayerOne()`.

Comment: OP will get same problem because methods are voids.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int CountScoreForPlayerOne()
{
    return PlayerOneScore++;
}

public int CountScoreForPlayerTwo()
{
    return PlayerTwoScore++;
}


if (CountScoreForPlayerOne() > CountScoreForPlayerTwo())
```

or

```
if (PlayerOneScore > PlayerTwoScore)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your method should have return type as int some thing like this:

```
 public int CountScoreForPlayerOne()
    {
        return Score++;
    }
    public int CountScoreForPlayerTwo()
    {
        return Score++;
    }
```

Then you can compare them like :

```
if (CountScoreForPlayerOne() > CountScoreForPlayerTwo())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no more cards the game is over!");
            Console.WriteLine($"{FirstPlayer} won the game");
        }
        else if (CountScoreForPlayerOne() < CountScoreForPlayerTwo())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no more cards the game is over!");
            Console.WriteLine($"{SecondPlayer} won the game");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no more cards the game is over!");
            Console.WriteLine("None won the game");
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"The final score is {FirstPlayer} {Score} - {SecondPlayer} {Score}");
```